# GDAL - Colourise polygon ndvi from sentinel 2-A data

Tags: gdal, polygon, gdalwarp, sentinel-2, gdal-translate

I am trying to take a `sentinel 2-A` `jp2` file and along with coordinates for a given `polygon`, generate the `colourised ndvi` of that polygon and where everything outside of the `polygon` is transparent. I then want to convert it to a `png`.

Given I know where in the map the polygon is located, I got the tile from sentinel that covers that location.

I then used `gdal_calc.py` with the `--projwin` option to limit the affected area to an area that contains the polygon. From there I am capable of colourising the resulting ndvi image.

Now I want to take the coordinates that I have for that `polygon`

```
"geo_json": {
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -0.5183105267238857,
          52.70755889050349
        ],
        [
          -0.5138501418205424,
          52.707355479805585
        ],
        [
          -0.5090106495574819,
          52.70424627990798
        ],
        [
          -0.5139704021925185,
          52.70204813127995
        ],
        [
          -0.5175195079000033,
          52.70175750758153
        ],
        [
          -0.5183105267238857,
          52.70755889050349
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

and apply them to the resulting ndvi image so that only the cells contained **inside** the polygon are **colourised** and **everything outside** of the polygon is **transparent**.

**I might not be following the right sequence of commands to achieve my goal, so am open to different approaches. I also don't know which of the `gdal` commands I now need to use to reach my goal.**

So far I have gone from taking this image:

[image]

And calculating the `colourised ndvi` for this section (picture from QGIS to illustrate):

[image]

The commands I've used so far have been:

`docker run --rm -v /Users:/Users osgeo/gdal:alpine-normal-latest gdal_calc.py --calc="((B.astype(float)-A.astype(float))/(B.astype(float)+A.astype(float)))" -A /Users/hyprstack/Documents/gdal-test/T30UXD_20210531T110621_B04.jp2 -B /Users/hyprstack/Documents/gdal-test/T30UXD_20210531T110621_B08.jp2 --outfile=/Users/hyprstack/Documents/gdal-test/ndvi.tif --type=Float32 --overwrite --projwin 652300 5861239 692881 5835090`

Which produced:

[image]

And then ran:

`docker run --rm -v /Users:/Users osgeo/gdal:alpine-normal-latest gdaldem color-relief /Users/hyprstack/Documents/gdal-test/ndvi.tif /Users/hyprstack/Documents/gdal-test/color_map.txt /Users/hyprstack/Documents/gdal-test/ndvi_color.tif`
To produce:
[image]

Comment: You mean you want to stack your result back onto the original image?  `gdalwarp` could do that, just specify both as inputs

Comment: No, I want to save the result as a png so I can display it in an app, using openlayers

Comment: From my original question "Now I want to take the coordinates that I have for that polygon and apply them to the resulting ndvi image so that only the cells contained inside the polygon are colourised and everything outside of the polygon is transparent."